# convert oct string to hex string in SML

Tags: sml

If the input is a string of oct number. For example, "\177". What is the best way to convert "\177" to its corresponding hex number string, namely "0x7F"?

I'm writing in **SML** and took a look at StringCvt, but didn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure about the subjective goodness, but here is what I managed to come up with.

```
- Int.fmt(StringCvt.HEX)(Char.ord(valOf(Char.fromCString("\\177"))));
val it = "7F" : string
```